# iPad rotation to landscape

Tags: ipad, rotation, uikit, landscape, portrait

Using iOS14.1, Swift5.3,

I try to rotate my iPad from portrait to landscape. However, the view is black on one side in landscape mode (see video).

What do I need to do in order to rotate an iPad ?

[image]

```
    open override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    open override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            guard let windowInterfaceOrientation = self.windowInterfaceOrientation else { return }

            if windowInterfaceOrientation.isLandscape {
                // activate landscape changes
                print("landscape now")
                print(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                print(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                self.view.setNeedsLayout()
                self.view.layoutSubviews()
            } else {
                // activate portrait changes
                print("portrait now")
                print(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                print(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                self.view.setNeedsLayout()
                self.view.layoutSubviews()
            }
        })
    }

    private var windowInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation? {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use `size` (which is passed to the function) instead of `UIScreen.main.bounds`

Comment: ok, I'll give that a try - thank you